# Need to use criteria from multiple tables to acquire data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, multiple-tables, cartesian-product

I'm having a bit of a hiccup regarding a particular SQL query.  I need to join data from two tables, while also limiting the data (but not necessarily grabbing it) by means of a third table.  The tables are as follows:

```
    MEMBERS(member_id,first_name,last_name)
    MEMBERS_GROUPS(member_id,group_id)
    CHARGES(charge_id,member_id,charge_amount,status)
```

I need to find all charges for all members of a specific group but I also want to grab the first and last name from the MEMBERS table.  The query I've come up with thus far is:

```
select c.*, m.first_name, m.last_name 
FROM charges c 
LEFT JOIN member m 
    ON c.member_id=m.member_id 
INNER JOIN members_groups mg 
    ON mg.group_id=1
```

i've also tried:

```
SELECT c.*, m.first_name, m.last_name 
FROM charges c, members_groups mg, member m 
WHERE c.member_id=mg.member_id 
   AND mg.group_id = 1 
   AND c.status='Valid' 
   AND c.member_id = m.member_id
```

…but neither returns the data I need.  I'm sure I'm overthinking this, but I can't for the life of me get the correct values.  I keep getting what appears to be the Cartesian product -- regardless, it's clearly returning too many rows and bad data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you need is to also restrict the INNER JOIN on `members_groups` to
those rows with `mg.member_id = m.member_id`:

```
SELECT c.*, m.first_name, m.last_name 
FROM charges c 
LEFT JOIN member m 
    ON c.member_id=m.member_id 
INNER JOIN members_groups mg 
    ON mg.group_id=1
    AND mg.member_id = m.member_id
```

Comment: *smacks forehead* Totally dumb. My original queries weren't working because there was more being appended to them further down the method.  Long story short, my extended "AND" query works -- in addition to the one you just posted. So, thank you.